# Exception caught after BrowserWindow is refactored to a separate file

Tags: javascript, electron

I've had managed to refactor a number of codes to separate files (and classes) all successfully but except for `BrowserWindow`. Does `BrowserWindow` handle things differently? I'm on Electron v.14.

My **index.js** that works before refactoring:

```
const electron = require('electron');        
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;                               

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {    
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,          
            contextIsolation: false,        
            enableRemoteModule: true       
          },
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/src/index.html`);
});
```

And following are the codes that breaks after I refactor BrowserWindow to a separate file (and the error that I get: `TypeError: MainWindow is not a constructor`):

**index.js**:

```
const electron = require('electron');        
const MainWindow = require('./app/main_window');        
const { app } = electron                            

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/src/index.html`);
});
```

**main_window.js** (./app/main_window.js):

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { BrowserWindow } = electron;

class MainWindow extends BrowserWindow {
    constructor() {
        super({                                 
            width: 300,
            height: 500,                       
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,          
                contextIsolation: false,        
                enableRemoteModule: true,       
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the class to import it in other files.

```
export class MainWindow extends BrowserWindow ....
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: omg ... I've been staring at my code checking line to line yet forgetting to export it. Well in my case it's `module.exports = MainWindow;` since I'm on node/commonjs. Thanks for pointing out though!